# Trouble uploading photo Grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

I'm following the Book Grails In Action. Section 5.5 is an example of how to upload a photo to a user profile.  Nothing complicated:

**Domain**

```
class Profile {
static belongsTo = User

byte[] photo
String fullName
String bio
String homepage
String email
String timezone
String country
String jabberAddress

String toString() {
    "Perfil para ${fullName} (${id})"
}

static constraints = {
    fullName(nullable: true)
    bio(nullable: true, maxSize: 1000)
    homepage(nullable: true, url: true)
    email(nullable: true, email: true)
    photo(nullable: true)
    country(nullable:true)
    timezone(nullable: true)
    jabberAddress(nullable: true, email: true)
}
```

}

Using the Profile and ImageController code in the source, I get this error trying to upload a photo (size less than 10kb):

Value too long for column "PHOTO BINARY(255)"

I have tried various methods to alter the column definition to accept a larger byte[], including:

1) in Profile constraints, setting maxSize: 1024*200
2) in Profile mappings, setting photo type:"byte[]", length:1024*200

in the mappings I have tried various combinations of type|sqlType:byte|byte[]|blob|binary but either the value is too long (for byte[]) or for the other types (eg, blob):

[B cannot be cast to java.sql.Blob

Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using photoUploadCommand? if yes, did you set constraints there?

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This wasn't working for me either while doing this [avatar image uploader](https://grails.org/Simple+Avatar+Uploader) test. 
I tried all the static mapping and other answers to no avail. What caught me out was the

`@Transactional(readOnly = true)`

line at the top of the (auto generated) Controller.  Setting it to `false` fixed the problem.

Putting in a temporary `failOnError:true` into the save method is a quick trick for spotting these problems. i.e.`domainObject.save(failOnError:true)`

I'd normally have used a Service with write access to save this image.

Answer (score 1):

Hello I have done this with oracle and h2 database. It worked for me...

Domain like

```
package com.so

class Profile {

String firstName
String lastName
String skillSet

byte[] profilePhoto

static belongsTo = [user:User]

static constraints = {
    firstName(blank:false)
    lastName(blank:false)
    skillSet(blank:false)
    profilePhoto(nullable:true) 
}

static mapping = {
    profilePhoto sqlType:'blob'
}
```

}

and controller like...

```
 def uploadProfilePhoto(){
    def file = new File(/C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg/)
    def profile = Profile.get(1)
    profile.profilePhoto = file.bytes
    profile.save()
    redirect action:'showProfilePhoto'
}
```

Hope this helps.

And also for MsSQL

```
 static mapping = {
    profilePhoto sqlType:'VARBINARY(max)'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define photo in the constraints like:

```
photo(nullable: true, maxSize: 32768))
```

for a photo of maximum size of 32k.

Comment: I followed the same book, what if you try with a very small image (less than 32k)?

Comment: I tried with various combinations and images very small (less than 5KB). I add static mapping = {photo column: "photo", sqlType: "blob"}. Nothing. Thanks again.